# How to pass javascript variable in .html() to php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am adding a text area on click of a particular div. It has `<form>` with textarea. I want to send the jquery variable to my php page when this submit button is pressed. How can this be achievable. I am confused alot with this . Being new to jquery dizzes me for now. Here is my code,

`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('.click_notes').on('click',function(){
 var tid = $(this).data('question-id'); 
 $(this).closest('ul').find('.demo').html("<div class='comment_form'><form action='submit.php' method='post'><textarea cols ='50' class='span10' name='notes' rows='6'></textarea><br><input class='btn btn-primary' name= 'submit_notes' type='submit' value='Add Notes'><input type='hidden' name='submitValue' value='"+tid+"' /></form><br></div>");
 });
});
</script>`
```

Comment: whats the result if you are using the above code ? does the form has the question id as hidden ?

Comment: have you tried ajax call, send your variable with data ?

Comment: I am not understanding how to move ahead from here.

Comment: @Naveen Yes, That is what i am trying todo. To send question_id to submit.php

Comment: @Sadeghbayan No not yet. How can I implement it. Can you please shed some light on this. WIll be really helpful

Comment: see my answer to get the idea.

Comment: Thanks for this. But shall I put this right after the code i sent above??

Comment: yes, you can put that after your form add to dom, see my updated answer

Comment: Can you show me where to add this. I am getting confused. Sorry for this but really confused. @Sadeghbayan

Comment: check my answer again

Comment: your code works fine in the fiddle i created. you can check it here https://jsfiddle.net/xe2Lhkpc/

Comment: What can i write on submit.php to view the retrieved question id and the text @Naveen

Comment: You can get the qid in submit.php like, ```$qid = $_POST['submitValue'];```

Comment: if(isset($_POST['submitValue']))

{

$qid = $_POST['submitValue'];


 }

Comment: Something like this? @Naveen

Comment: Yes. you can check like that.

Comment: Thanks Yes I got this on submit.php .. the qid.. Now for the text in textarea? How that can be retrieved. @Naveen

Comment: use the name of the inputs as key of $_POST array to get their values. ```if(isset($_POST['notes'])) { $notes = $_POST['notes'];```

Comment: Thanks  a ton !!! @Naveen

Comment: Thank you for your precious time. @Sadeghbayan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works fine in the fiddle I created here -> https://jsfiddle.net/xe2Lhkpc/

use the name of the inputs as key of $_POST array to get their values.

```
if(isset($_POST['submitValue'])) { $qid = $_POST['submitValue']; } 

if(isset($_POST['notes'])) { $notes = $_POST['notes']; }
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Highly appreciated. One question. How can I show or hide this text area on clicking somewhere on the page or the label

Comment: check this fiddle. Added X mark to close. https://jsfiddle.net/z7wqcdor/

Comment: Yes its working well but how to align this at right most corner of the text box. Currently it appears at the leftmost corner.

Answer (score 1):

You should send your data after form submitted, something like this
:

```
    $(".comment_form form").submit(function(e) {


    var form = $(this);
    var url = form.attr('action');

    $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: url,
           data: form.serialize(), // serializes the form's elements.
           success: function(data)
           {
               alert(data); // show response from the php script.
           }
         });

    e.preventDefault(); // avoid to execute the actual submit of the form.
});
```

you can assign event after insert your form.

```
// handling with the promise

$(this).closest('ul').find('.demo').html("<div class='comment_form'><form action='submit.php' method='post'></form><br></div>").promise().done(function () {
       // your ajax call
  });;
```

Comment: This does not shows anything. Rather now i am not obtaining any textarea on click to Add notes div